# Connecting to SoftEther from Ubuntu 18

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn, aws, l2tp

I have installed a Softether VPN server on AWS through its Marketplace [click here to check the product](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Cloud-Infrastructure-Services-VPN-Server-Solution-/B08BW8J439).

I set up the server. I have an Ubuntu 18 Machine which I want to set up a client to connect to this server. For some reason, I am unable to do so neither using OpenVPN nor l2tp. Note that I have enable L2TP connections on the server.

I am unable to understand what should be done in order to connect in either protocols to the softether server from Ubuntu 18

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances/devices & cloud use do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18.  (Ubuntu has had *yy* releases since 2016, and they are different products to the standard *yy.mm* format releases)

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu <= 20.04, try the newer network-manager-l2tp packages from https://launchpad.net/~nm-l2tp/+archive/ubuntu/network-manager-l2tp . If you have anything in the Phase 1 & 2 input boxes, delete their contents. The newer nm-l2tp versions use a combination of Win10 & iOS IKEv1 proposals for phase 1 & 2 instead of using the libreswan or strongswan defaults. If you are still have issues, try switching from strongswan to libreswan with `sudo apt install libreswan`